# What does these settings mean for Block Public Access settings in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am struggling with understanding this section of the AWS document, can a kind soul help to explain these in simpler term?

This is the document page
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html

The four settings for Block Public Access:
`BlockPublicAcls`, `IgnorePublicAcls`, `BlockPublicPolicy`, `RestrictPublicBuckets`.

How does `BlockPublicAcls` and `IgnorePublicAcls` work differently?

How does `BlockPublicPolicy` and `RestrictPublicBuckets` work differently?

And the paragraph below... the setting will passthrough or apply to the bucket?

> Access points don't have ACLs associated with them. If you apply this
> setting to an access point, it acts as a passthrough to the underlying
> bucket. If an access point has this setting enabled, requests made
> through the access point behave as though the underlying bucket has
> this setting enabled, regardless of whether the bucket actually has
> this setting enabled.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can see this can be confusing, however the below should help to illustrate the usage of these.

- `BlockPublicAcls` - This prevents any **new** ACLs to be created or **existing** ACLs being modified which enable public access to the object. With this alone existing ACLs will not be affected.
- `IgnorePublicAcls` - Any ACLs actions that exist with public access will be ignored, this does not prevent them being created but prevents their effects.
- `BlockPublicPolicy` - This prevents a bucket policy containing public actions from being created or modified on an S3 bucket, the bucket itself will still allow the existing policy.
- `RestrictPublicBuckets` - This will prevent non AWS services or authorized users (such as an IAM user or role) from being able to publicly access objects in the bucket.

Comment: Thanks! This is so much easier to understand!

Comment: No problem have a great day :)

Answer (score 9):

> How does BlockPublicAcls and IgnorePublicAcls work differently?

For example, AWS S3 api has a call such as [put-object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html) have option `--acl`. With this you can not only upload object, but also make it publicly available.

When `Block Public Access` is off, call

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket some-bucket --acl public-read --key test.file
```

successes, and `test.file` will be not only uploaded, but also publicly available.

Now, if you enable:

- `BlockPublicAcls`:  the above **API will fail**. Any API which allows `--acl public-read` will be rejected. So `test.file` won't be uploaded.
- `IgnorePublicAcls`: **API call succeeds**. The file is uploaded, but option `--acl public-read` is **ignored** and the file is private.

> How does BlockPublicPolicy and RestrictPublicBuckets work differently?

Similarly, you can use [put-bucket-policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-policy.html) to apply public bucket policies, e.g.:

```
{
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": "*",
         "Action": "s3:GetObject",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

with

```
aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket MyBucket --policy file://policy.json
```

Now, if you enable:

- `BlockPublicPolicy` the above **API will fail**, because the policy allows for public API.
- `RestrictPublicBuckets` the above **API will succeed**, and the bucket policy will be applied.  However, the policy will be **ignored**, and objects will be private. Disabling `RestrictPublicBuckets` will make the policy to work, and the objects will be publicly available.

#### S3 Access points

There are **new ways of controlling access** to your objects. Instead of using AWS default S3 endpoint, like in the examples above, you can create your own endpoints and use that. For example:

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket some-bucket --acl public-read --key test.file --endpoint-url https://<endpoint-name>-<account-id>.s3-accesspoint.<region>.amazonaws.com
```

A single bucket can have many access points and its endpoints for different purposes. Also, **each access point has its own** `Block Public Access` settings and access point policy (similar to bucket policy). The options in `Block Public Access` for access points work similarly as for bucket, with the exceptions mentioned in the docs you cited.

Comment: Thanks! This help a lot! I have a better understanding of the settings now!